# Removing content from folder in matlab

Tags: matlab, directory

In the matlab code I am generating files at after specific iterations in a file called
'results' in present working directory. When I want to run the code next time, files crated by previous run are also present in the results folder. 
In C I would do that as

```
(void) system("rm -rf results/*");
```

How can I remove content of folder 'results' every time code starts to execute? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`system('rm -rf results/*')` should be exactly the same as your C code.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can also use the built-in `rmdir()` function with the `s` argument to remove all subfolders and files in the given folder:

```
rmdir('results', 's')
```

Please note that your `results` folder will also be removed, so your code would need to create an empty folder again (see `mkdir()`).

Further, I suggest to always use absolute file paths.

Comment: One painful problem is that MATLAB stops the script and asks you a question `remove entire contents of output? (yes or no)`.

Comment: Hi @ar2015, haven't had this before and cannot reproduce. As I'm curious, could you please post an example how to provoke?

Comment: sorry, I think this is an `octave` issue.